# JSON to XML in go lang

Tags: json, go, xml-to-json

Hi I am trying the below code in go lang, where i have to change a json data to xml and pass it to another service. Below is the function that i tried for json to xml conversion

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
)

type Address struct {
        Address1 string `json:"Address1"`
        Address2  string    `json:"Address2"`
        city  string    `json:"city"`
        state  string    `json:"state"`
        zipcode  string    `json:"zipcode"`
}

func main() {
    jsonData := `{  "Address1": "777 Brockton Avenue",
  "Address2": "string",
  "city": "Abington",
  "state": "MA",
  "zipcode": "2351"}`
    var person Address
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonData), &person)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    xmlData, err := xml.Marshal(person)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(xmlData))
}
```

The output is as below

```
<Address><Address1>777 Brockton Avenue</Address1><Address2>string</Address2></Address>
```

My expected output is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<AddressValidateRequest USERID="702DIGIT27hfgjkf41">
  <Address>
    <Address1>777 Brockton Avenue</Address1>
    <Address2>string</Address2>
    <City>Abington</City>
    <State>MA</State>
    <Zip5>2351</Zip5>
    <Zip4/>
  </Address>
</AddressValidateRequest>
```

I am quite new to the language,any guidance is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create another struct as `AddressValidateRequest` with `Name`, `UserID` and `Address` fields. As this structure is defined based on the output you expected.

Also first character should be in uppercase letter for the `City`, `State` and `Zipcode` fields. If not they'll not included in the xml output.

Here is the code

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
)

type Address struct {
    Address1 string `json:"Address1"`
    Address2 string `json:"Address2"`
    City     string `json:"city"`
    State    string `json:"state"`
    Zip5     string `json:"zipcode"`
    Zip4     string `json:"Zip4"`
}

type AddressValidateRequest struct {
    Name string  `xml:"AddressValidateRequest"`
    UserID  string  `xml:"USERID,attr"`
    Address Address `xml:"Address"`
}

func main() {
    jsonData := `{  
        "Address1": "777 Brockton Avenue",
        "Address2": "string",
        "city": "Abington",
        "state": "MA",
        "zipcode": "2351"
    }`

    var person Address
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonData), &person)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    req := AddressValidateRequest{
        UserID:  "702DIGIT2741",
        Address: person,
    }

    xmlData, err := xml.MarshalIndent(req, "", " ")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%s%s \n", xml.Header, string(xmlData))

}
```