# Converting JSON to XML in golang

Tags: json, xml, go, go-gin

Im trying to receive data as json then convert the data to xml before sending the data to another api, then receive the data in xml and convert it to json so that I can give it as my response.

The second party api receives the xml in this format:

```
<AutoCreate>
<Request>
<APIUsername>gfgergerge</APIUsername>
<APIPassword>gregrgregre</APIPassword>
<Method>gergrgreg</Method>
</Request>
</AutoCreate>
```

After using online converters I got this json, which Im trying to now convert it back to xml in my go code, so that I can send it to the api so that I get an xml response, which I need to convert it back to json:

```
{
  "AutoCreate": {
    "Request": {
      "APIUsername": "gfgergerge",
      "APIPassword": "gregrgregre",
      "Method": "gergrgreg"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JSON to XML in go lang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76661477/json-to-xml-in-go-lang)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I understand the task, but not what problem you are facing. Start first and when you have an actual problem, come back here. Maybe also take the [tour] and read [ask] again.

Comment: So what's your question?